# What is the difference between "jboss-admin" and "jboss-cli" in Jboss 7

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I started learning about JBoss 7 through a tutorial, by experimenting on an existing known Jboss server setup. The tutorial mentions that

> Command Line Interface (CLI), can be found in the JBOSS_HOME/bin folder.
>
> Just launch the `jboss-admin.bat` script (or `jboss-admin.sh` for Linux users) and you will be able to manage the application server via a shell interface

However, I did not find any `jboss-admin` in my bin folder, and apart from that I found `jboss-cli` which seems similar to `jboss-admin`

So what exactly is the difference between them? Why does my JBoss 7 setup miss `jboss-admin`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Jan 24, 2012 `jboss-admin.[sh,bat]` was renamed to `jboss-cli.[sh,bat]`

See https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as/commit/85a8225dd1017969e5efc8fdc55c23fc94d51cda

Comment: Thanks!! Strange I didn't find this information with a Google search!